# Gelfand-Mazur complex part mean what it says?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

This question pertains to the **complex** Gelfand/Mazur theorem.
Mazur/Gelfand says normed division algebra over the complex numbers is isomorphic to the complex numbers.
Therefore, is the statement true: The **ONLY** normed division algebra over complex numbers is the complex numbers? And, therefore, is this statement true: a normed division algebra over complex numbers is **not** isomorphic to the reals or quaternions. (There is another post here that appears to confirm the quaternion side of this question but not for the real side.)
Some argue that this was not what the theorem meant because the complex numbers can be seen to contain the reals. But that would seem to require the theorem to say that a normed division algebra over the complex numbers is isomorphic to the reals and complex or some kind of transitivity group argument would then put it isomorphic with quaternions (which does not seem to be right.)
Clarification: this question is **NOT** about normed division algebra over real numbers but about normed division algebra over **complex**.

Comment: There is a real part of the theorem that says that a normed division algebra over the reals is isomorphic to the reals, or the complex, or the quaternions. But this question is asking about the complex part of the theorem which says that a normed division algebra over the complex numbers is isomorphic to the complex numbers.

Comment: $\Bbb{R,H}$ are real algebras, not complex algebras (as $jz  =\overline{z}j \ne zj$). Every complex normed division algebra is a real normed division algebra. When restricting to complex algebras [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) gives a simple argument. Classifying the real normed division algebras is non-trivial, is it what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you. Several published sources consulted for this question described Gelfand/Mazur as two separate theorems or to the theorem as having two parts. Also, the other post referred to above states that the quaternions are a real Banach algebra (and presumably the reals would be a real Banach algebra) but not a complex Banach algebra. Why does that sound like it is saying something different? It seems correct to say that the reals, complex and quaternions are real normed division algebras but only the complex are a complex division algebra. Is that wrong?

Comment: Saying something different from what. A $k$-algebra is a ring $R$ where we can take polynomials $f,g \in k[x]$ and evaluate $f(a)g(a)$ for $a \in R$ in a natural way.

Answer (score 1):

For [Banach Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra), Wikipedia states, "The only complex Banach algebra which is a division algebra is the complexes. (This is known as the Gelfand–Mazur theorem.)" The "only" was the qualifier this question was asking to be confirmed. (Apologies for asking such a fundamental question.) Also, "Unital Banach algebras over the complex field provide a general setting to develop spectral theory."
*Rickart, C. E.*, [**An elementary proof of a fundamental theorem in the theory of Banach algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1028998012),  says, "Mazur-Gelfand ... is directly equivalent to the existence of a spectrum for elements of a normed algebra."
Therefore, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ are not complex Banach algebras. If given a Banach algebra over the complex then it is **only** isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.